Kendo React Grid Renders Details on Each Update
I have a React project using Kendo React Grid.  The grid has details and those details are loading dynamically from a web API on expand.
It seems like Kendo is re-rendering the details component (thus re-calling the API) each time ANY property on the state object is changed.  As a test, I expanded one row of the grid and the API was called as it should be.  I then pressed a button that just sets a bool property of the state to show a dialog (this property is not referenced in the grid at all) and it re-rendered everything and called the API again for the data.
Is there a way to prevent it from re-rendering this EVERY time?  Why would it need to update that component on every possible state change?
